# Google Docs - Is any function support google docs (no google sheet) select value from range?

Tags: google-docs

Bellowing is example fuction in Microsoft Word 2016. Google Docs have function or any extension support select value from range?

I only few line need select from drop down. So i don't want using Google Sheet, difficult convert linked table of content, different page header footer or other to sheet.

[image: Drop-Down List Content Control]

[image: Example Content Control Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get reponse from [Google Docs Editors Community](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/9603437?hl=en) .

Bellowing is the response.

That capability currently isn't available in Docs. To help influence future feature changes or additions in Docs, I encourage you to provide feedback about this directly to the Docs team by following these steps:

Open a document.

Click **Help > Report a problem.**

Enter your feedback.
Although the product team is unable to respond to individual users directly, they review this feedback regularly and use it to help improve the product over time. The more users who have this request, the more likely it is the team will make a change.

> So, conclusion. Google doesn't support yet.